# Synchronize two vobs on two different hosts

Tags: clearcase

Hi every one am new the clear case I need to keep synchronized the already replicated vobs how do I do that can any one help me in steps wise I appreciate your time and help 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the Vob is already replicated (meaning with [ClearCase multisite](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/ccmulticoll)), then it mostly is a matter of running [`multitool syncreplica`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_ref.doc/topics/mt_syncreplica.htm):

```
host1:
multitool syncreplica -export -fship replica:<replica_tag>@\aPVob

host2:
cd /opt/rational/clearcase/shipping/ms_ship/incoming
sudo -u vobadm /opt/rational/clearcase/bin/multitool syncreplica -import /opt/rational/clearcase/shipping/ms_ship/incoming/sync_*_2015-07-16T07*
```

Comment: Thank you vonc can you elaborate the host 2 you explained I didn't really get it

Comment: @Madhumitha those are the command that needs to be executed on host2: if syncreplaca -export has exported any paquet, you would see those paquets on host2 in /opt/rational/clearcase/shipping/ms_ship/incoming