# How can I create a Jenkins job that checks synchronization of clearcase vob's between two servers

Tags: java, jenkins, clearcase, release-management

Hi guys am new to the release engineering can you guys Help me in setting up a Jenkins jobs that checks every night.
Job needs to compare the two vob's server if they are out of synch the job should fail and notify to the user.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If your Jenkins server has access to the second host (the one which receives paquets from the first host, as I illustrated in "[Synchronize two vobs on two different hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31446196/6309)"), all the job needs to do is:

- to access the `/opt/rational/clearcase/shipping/ms_ship/incoming` folder on host2
- check for any `sync_*_2015-07-16T07*` files (they are named after the date of the export)

If there are any (meaning those files were not for some reason imported on host2), then the job can fail and send an email.